Plugin for translation from one account and posting in different account
this is my first post in this part of Stackexchange. Here is my situation and my question:
I own two wordpress blogs in two different hostings and domains, one in each language (pt-BR and en-US). Both are about the same subject, so the posts often times would fit in both languages' blogs. What I am looking for is a way of:
(1) automatically translating a post from pt-BR to en-US or en-US to pt-BR and
(2) post said translated post in the opposite blog.
So basically if I generate content in English I want an automatic way of translating such post and posting it in the corresponding/opposite blog. All of this without worring about importing/loading pictures, links, etc.
Thank you for your help,
